Dropped plot line in Dafydd ab Hugh's DS9 novel "Fallen Heroes"
In Dafydd ab Hugh's DS9 novel, "Fallen Heroes," the Odo and Quark are displaced into a future in which DS9 is devastated and almost everyone is dead, and the plot alternates between the past story in which all the other protagonists deal with an attack on the station, while Odo and Quark attempt in the future to learn what happened, so that if they get back to the past they can avert the disaster.
When they met Jake, who is the only living person onboard except for Molly O'Brien, Jake tells Odo,

You see, when you disappeared before the attack, some people figured
that you had something to do with it -- that you planned it.

but provides no other details, while in the past scenes this never comes up (we see no one talking about this suspicion, and no real oppotunities for Jake to hear such thoughts anyway).
Has the author (or anyone else) indicated that the scene with Jake is a reference to a plot line about suspicion of Odo in an earlier draft that was later (incompletely) removed?
